# Mapping a list of objects via fluent nhibernate

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, many-to-many, domain-driven-design

I'm tackling with a little bit complex business business but for making it simple I ask my question in another way.
suppose a blogTag and Blog, I'm gonna to assign several tag for every blogpost. my blogTag model is this one:

```
  public class BlogTag 
    {  
       public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

and my Blog:

```
public class Blog
     {

        private IList<BlogTag> _blogTags;

        public Guid Id { get; set;}

        public IList<BlogTag> BlogTag
            {
                get { return _blogTags; }
                set { _blogTags = value; }
            }
     }
```

it seems to be a many to many relationship between them to achieve it. but the main issue is that I want to make the tag as Value Object(DDD) and I have to map it via component operand (fluent nhibernate) in order to make the Name of tag as primary key(not an int or Guid). so I've tried this on mapping:

```
public sealed class BlogMapping : ClassMap<Blog>
    {
        public BlogMapping()
        {
            Table("Blog");
            Not.LazyLoad();
            Id(b => b.Id).GeneratedBy.GuidComb();

            HasManyToMany(b => b.BlogTag)
                .Schema("Blogs")
                .ParentKeyColumn("Id")
                .Table("BlogTag")
                .ChildKeyColumn("Name")
                .Component(t =>
                {
                    t.Map(bt => bt.IsDeleted);
                    t.Map(bt => bt.Count);
                    t.Map(bt => bt.CreationTime);
                })
               .Inverse().AsSet();
             }
        }
```

but it doesn't make any kind of many to many relationship when I use component inside HasManyToMany. how can I do that!? thanks